# Google Analytics Api landingPagePath dimension for mcf not supported yet

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can use 'landing page URL path' dimension in google analytics reporting Multi channel funnels as you can see in the attached image

[image: landing page URL path dimension]

but i can't through the api, because its not mcf dimension according to the dimensions list
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/

So will it be supported soon? and is there any workaround solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack is not google support we cant tell you when it will be supported.   Might try https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: Actually i posted here because on their support page thats what they said
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/help

Comment: Unfortunately stack isn't Google support while they do check stack you won't get any official anwsers from them hete

Comment: But i guess you are right as this is a feature request.